# Dont Remove programs on Turn OFF

Tags: compact-framework

Hi all I have a Windows CE 6.0 device. I installed SqlServecCompact3.5 but the device removes the program when I power off the device.

What Do I have to do for it not to reinstall programs I have installed?

Comment: Does it remove the software, or just stop running?

Comment: Remove program when turn off delete in windows system files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Windows CE devices reset to factory default if you pull the battery.  You will want to refer to the vendor's documentation to determine the appropriate way to restore the device.  Typically there are one or more persistent storage areas and a mechanism to auto-run CAB installs, file copies, and registry updates upon a cold-boot restart.  These allow you to rebuild the device.